Content Security Policy - URL mismatch though the directive matches
I am getting the following error thrown for CSP report only.

[Report Only] Refused to frame 'https://app.example.in/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://*.example.in".

What is wrong in the mentioned directive? Though the URL matches the directive, the error is thrown.
